# how to enable just one tab in jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

i for create tab in asp.net use jqueryui tab and write this code for create tab

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="context-tab"><a id="recent-tab" href="#iframe1">Recent</a></li>
                <li class="context-tab"><a id="popular-tab" href="#iframe2">Popular</a></li>
                <li class="context-tab"><a id="random-tab" href="#iframe3">Random</a></li>
                <li class="context-tab"><a id="question-tab" href="#iframe4">By Question</a></li>

            </ul>
            <iframe id="iframe1" src="Default3.aspx" style="width: 100%;" height="900"></iframe>

            <iframe id="iframe2" src="Default4.aspx" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>

            <iframe id="iframe3" src="Default5.aspx" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>

            <iframe id="iframe4" src="Default6.aspx" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
        <a id="goNext" href="#" style="display: none;">Next</a>
        </div>

     <script>
         $(function () {
             var $tabs = $("#tabs");
             $tabs.tabs();
             $tabs.tabs("option", 'disabled', [1, 2, 3]);
             function getSelectedTabIndex() {
                 return $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
             }


             $("#goNext").click(function () {
                 var b = getSelectedTabIndex() + 1;
                 $tabs.tabs('enable', b);
                 $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', b);
                 $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected', b);
             });
         });
    </script>
```

i want Only one tab can be active at any time and all And the rest of the tabs are not active. please help me. thanks all.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen6862/C2sna/)

Comment: Create jsfiddle, Also tell us where you failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#goNext").click(function () {
    var b = getSelectedTabIndex() + 1;

    // Disable the rest of the tabs are not active
    var c = $tabs.find("ul li").size();
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        $tabs.tabs("disable", i);
    }

    $tabs.tabs('enable', b);
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', b);
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected', b);
});
```

Comment: this code not work, example when form load recent-tab in selected and when user click next link popular-tab is selected but recent-tab is active i want recent-tab and random-tab,question-tabis disabled